# current route name is null on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Always getting `null` when I try to find current page. How do I get current page?

```
print('current page ${ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name}');
```

my end goal is,

```
if(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name == 'homePage'){
showAlert()
}
```

my MaterialApp

```
 MaterialApp(
        onGenerateRoute: CustomRouter.generateRoute,
...

class CustomRouter {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final Arguments arguments = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case Splash.route:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Splash());
```

Comment: You overrode the route settings by generating a completely new `MaterialPageRoute` route builder. You didn't provide your route with a name when you generated it and you didn't provide it the existing settings. Ergo, the route's name will be null.

Comment: @Akif Don't answer with links and no context. The answer becomes useless if the link ever changes, expires, or becomes invalid.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, as an answer for the next visitors to this page, passing the RouteSettings parameter is required as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50192#issuecomment-590307455).

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: settings,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        //some custom code

        return _data[settings.name](context);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, finally a solution - now to update +60 routes.

Answer (score 2):

```
    ...
```

MaterialPageRoute(
settings: settings,    // Important!!!
...
)

Answer (score 2):

Also it can related about wrong BuildContext, you must be ensure the given buildcontext must be same as your page buildcontext if it is not, you will get null or wrong route.

```
ModalRoute.of(currentPageContext)?.settings.name;
```

Comment: this is not the solution. it's should be null. this is the https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668286/8822337

Comment: @BISTech I was getting null and I checked my code, after that I found the my problem. My problem was using the wrong build context and for that reason, settings.name was was returning the null (as like your situation but different reason.). So this answer is correct answer too but not for your exact problem. I write it here because if any one google the problem, he or she can check the build context is correct or not correct, and if its not using the correct page buildcontext, he or she can fix the code. Thanks!